# Why argument list as ArraySeq?

Tags: clojure, arguments

Consider the following function:

```
user> (defn first-args [& args]
            (args 0))
#'user/first-args
user> (first-args 1 2 3) ;=> clojure.lang.ArraySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

Why is the argument list a `clojure.lang.ArraySeq` and not something much more common like a `PersistentVector`? Or why doesn't `ArraySeq` implement `IFn`? Performance reasons? Seems like you have to know the underlying implementation of things a bit while doing Clojure. Feel free to enlighten me.

PS: this question is not about "is this idiomatic or not?" Just asking why this is like it is.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
(defn first-args [& args]
  (first args))

(apply first-args (range)) 
;=> 0
```

You can apply a function to an infinite argument sequence, consuming items only as needed. If `&` args were required to be a vector (or anything more concrete than an ISeq), this would be impossible.

As for why seqs aren't callable: it would encourage using them in a way that performs very poorly.

Answer (score 5):

Other answers are already good, but just wanted to present an alternative to achieve the same effect:

```
(defn first-args [first-arg & others] 
  first-arg)

(first-args 1 2 3)
=> 1
```

i.e. you can explicitly name the first argument in the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `args` as a function in line 2. What you want is actually:

```
(defn first-args [& args]
  (first args))
```

ArraySeq is actually more 'common' than Vector because Vector inherits ISeq. Which is why you can't do `(get args 0)` here, which seems to be what you want to call, because that only works for maps and vectors, and not any ISeq (such as list).

Comment: I wanted to use the vector as a function, like ([1 2 3] 0) => 1. But then I discovered it wasn't a regular vector.

Comment: PersistentVector doesn't implement ISeq; it is seqable, but not a seq. But even if it were I don't see how we could then conclude that ArraySeq is more "common" than a vector.